# Use TEMPLATEPATH for custom url

Tags: template-include

I have a code in below and as you can see I have a condition to read custom template for desktop and mobile. Now I want to use a custom url instead of a file.For example I want to include a page site.com/test instead of index.php

```
<?php
// Use anywhere
if ( muneeb_wp_is_mobile() ){
 include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/index-mobile.php');
}
else{
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/index-desktop.php');
} ?>
```

Can I use this?

```
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/site.com/page1');
```

Comment: you can't `require` or `include` URLs like that in PHP, but even if you could it wouldn't execute the PHP there it would just load the final output the same as if you loaded it in the browser directly. I do not believe `TEMPLATEPATH` is in any way related to what you're hoping to achieve, this is an X Y problem.

Comment: So how can I do that?

Comment: Do which? I mentioned several things and it's unclear which you were referring to. Do you mean how do I take PHP on a remote URL and execute it on my server? Or do you mean how do I take the content/output of a URL and include it on my page? And is that URL on the same server? Be clear, and be very specific/explicit about what you want to do